# Como esperar a requisição acabar para pegar os dados?

Tags: android, retrofit

Preciso pegar os dados que vem dentro de um response, mas quando dou um get no objeto do response dá erro dizendo que está null. Acho que tem alguma coisa a ver com o meu get estar sendo feito antes do response chegar, mas não sei como consertar isso. Segue abaixo os códigos:

O OnResponse:

```java
@Override
    public void onResponse(Call<ResponseDTO> call, Response<ResponseDTO> response) {

        if(response.isSuccessful()) {

            Log.i("conexao", "succesful");

            System.out.println("conectou");

            responseDTO = response.body();

            System.out.println(response.code());

            for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                Log.i("hq", responseDTO.getData().getComics().get(i).getTitle());
            }


        } else {

            Log.i("conexao", "not succesful");
            System.out.println("conectou mas deu errado");
            //responseDTO = null;
        }
    }
```

Objeto do Response (o que eu quero pegar é esse atributo data, porém acusa que está null)

```java
public class ResponseDTO {

    private String code;
    private String status;
    private MarvelData data;

    public ResponseDTO(String code, String status, MarvelData data) {
        this.code = code;
        this.status = status;
        this.data = data;
    }
 //Gets e sets...
}
```

Onde eu estou chamando os métodos:

```java
public class ComicFacade {
    Controller comicController;
    ResponseDTO responseDTO;
    MarvelData marvelData;

    public ComicFacade() {
        this.comicController = new Controller();
        this.comicController.create();

        this.responseDTO = comicController.getResponseDTO();
    }

    public List<Comic> getComics() {
        marvelData = responseDTO.getData();
        return marvelData.getComics();
    }
}
```

Erro:

```java
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.ecommercemarvel/com.example.ecommercemarvel.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.example.ecommercemarvel.model.MarvelData com.example.ecommercemarvel.model.ResponseDTO.getData()' on a null object reference
```

Como eu faço para pegar os dados só quando a requisição tiver acabado?